# IOS, swift - UICollectionReusableView not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode9

I want to make collection view header but it isn't working.

**Storyboard**

[image]

**On device**

[image]

My code below is not working, print("ssssss") don't show.

```swift
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        print("sssssss")
        switch kind {

        case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:

            let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind,
                                                                             withReuseIdentifier: "mypageheader",
                                                                             for: indexPath) as! MyPageHeaderView
            headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue;
            return headerView

        default:

            assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
        }
    }
```

on viewDidLoad()

```swift
self.collectionView?.register(MyPageViewController.self,forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader,withReuseIdentifier: "mypageheader")
```

Comment: Shouldn't you do `register(MyPageHeaderView.self;...` instead?

Comment: Yes, (s)he should... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement [this delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617702-collectionview):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 100)
}
```

Don't forget to setup the [`delegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout) of your `collectionView` in the storyboard!

Comment: @이예린, did you set the `delegate` outlet of the `collectionView` to the `ViewController`?

Comment: yes, and implement UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout. can't call this method ((override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView ))

Comment: @이예린, please, place a breakpoint inside `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` method from my answer and tell me whether it's called or not.

Comment: i was using open source, but the 'referenceSizeForHeaderInSection' function was defined differently. thank you.!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are configuring custom view via .xib/storyboard, you **don't need** to add the following method in the viewDidload:

```
self.collectionView?.register(MyPageViewController.self,forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader,withReuseIdentifier: "mypageheader")
```

Select the view in storyboard and Go to the identity inspector, and link the `Class` nad `Module`

[image]

Then go to the attribute inspector and ann the identifier:

[image]

And make sure to add the method in your code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
  let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "HomeListTopCollectionReusableViewId", for: indexPath) as! HomeListTopCollectionReusableView
  return header
}
```